# Include files from outer directory

Tags: python, macos

I have this directory structure:

```
__init__.py
/Report
    ReportData.py
    __init__.py
/Technology
    TechnologyRSS.py
    __init__.py
/International_news
    International.py
    __init__.py
```

If I put `from ..Report.ReportData import Report` I'll get the next error.

**Input**

```
python3 TechnologyRSS.py
```

**Output**

```
  File "TechnologyRSS.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..Report.ReportData import Report # Report class.
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

I put `from __future__ import absolute_import` in all of my files and nothing has changed.

Also I tried to execute my script using this command via terminal:

**Input**

```
python ./Technology/TechnologyRSS.py
```

**Output**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Technology/TechnologyRSS.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .Report.ReportData import Report # Report class.
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Python version: `3.4.3`

Comment: Probably (e.g. if it's on your Python path), but it's not ideal. How have you ended up with that structure?

Comment: Report.py contains a general class I need to access it from diferents sub-dirs.

Comment: Are all of these files within a package? *Could* they be?

Comment: Package? Sorry I'm new in python.

Comment: @Kevin I think the OP wants access the other way, but a couple of `__init__.py`s would certainly help them out.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think a package would resolve my problems? But the file is in another dir, is there a problem with that?

Comment: What do you mean *"in another dir"*? If all of the directories are in the same package, you can do an intra-package import. If the directory is on the path, you can do a standard import. Please read and follow the tutorial, it covers all of this.

Comment: Let me update the information @jonrsharpe.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Tutorial shows me how to import `TechnologyRSS.py` and `International.py` to `Report.py` and not the inverse.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

Comment: @jonrsharpe I update the information and my module structure, and I have another error. Check the new information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76579/discussion-between-jastertdc-clan-and-jonrsharpe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import # must be first line in file
from ..report import report # could be from .report import report I forget which one, that's what happens when you depend on IDE code completion as a crutch :)
```

**Modified the above**
The answer I had above is applicable to Python 2.7 but python3 is different. There you would have no need for absolute_import, that is the default behavior
You are running your file wrong. Suppose this is your directory structure

```
/home/itsme/myproj/
    __init__.py
    /Report
         ReportData.py
         __init__.py
    /Technology
        TechnologyRSS.py
        __init__.py
    /International_news
        International.py
        __init__.py
```

modify

> TechnologyRSS.py

```
from Report.ReportData import Report
... # rest of your code
```

Then while in /home/itsme/myproj/ exec this

```
python3 -m Technology.TechnologyRSS
```

Of course for this to have any effect, TechnologyRSS needs to be runnable of course

Comment: I tried the code you put me, and I have the next error                      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TechnologyRSS.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..Report import Report
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

Comment: I am guessing your modules do not have     __init__.py    files?

Comment: @pbhowmick given that the OP doesn't show any, it's probably safe to assume as much!

Comment: I have __init__.py files in both dirs @pbhowmick

Comment: In all the modules? (includes the entire hierarchy of modules)

Comment: Can you recheck my problem ? @pbhowmick